# How do i ignore specific shapes on image processing, OpenCV, Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, image-segmentation

I am working on cell segmentation and tracking. I've set of microscopical images. There are some circular noises caused by lamella. When I'm using my algorithm that may cause loss of cells some parts. I want to say to my program, "hey look those circular things are just noise, and just deny it, and work on real cell's membrane." The other one is, micro noises. There are some points with high or low contrast. I want to say to my program, "Hey, deny points, if its 10x10 pixels radius are the same with backgrounds contrast."

Work platform: Python 3.7.2, OpenCV 3.4.5

I hope, i clearly mentioned what my problem is. I am sharing one of those images.

4 circles on left are point noises.
2 circles on right are lamella noises.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pe7EO.jpg)

```
import numpy
import cv2 as cv
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
img = cv.imread('test001.tif')
gg = img.copy()
img_gray = cv.cvtColor(gg, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

clache = cv.createCLAHE(clipLimit=2.0, tileGridSize=(8,8))
img_gray = clache.apply(img_gray)

_, img_bin = cv.threshold(img_gray, 50, 255,
        cv.THRESH_OTSU)

img_bin = cv.morphologyEx(img_bin, cv.MORPH_OPEN,
        numpy.ones((10, 9), dtype=int))

img_bin = cv.morphologyEx(img_bin, cv.MORPH_DILATE,
        numpy.ones((5, 5), dtype=int), iterations= 1)


def segment(im1, img):
    #morphological transformations
    border = cv.dilate(img, None, iterations=10)
    border = border - cv.erode(border, None, iterations=1)
    #invert the image so black becomes white, and vice versa
    img = -img
    #applies distance transform and shows visualization
    dt = cv.distanceTransform(img, 2, 3)
    dt = ((dt - dt.min()) / (dt.max() - dt.min()) * 255).astype(numpy.uint8)
    #reapply contrast to strengthen boundaries
    clache = cv.createCLAHE(clipLimit=2.0, tileGridSize=(8,8))
    dt = clache.apply(dt)
    #rethreshold the image
    _, dt = cv.threshold(dt, 127, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY)

    ret, markers = cv.connectedComponents(dt)
    markers = markers+1
    # Complete the markers
    markers[border == 255] = 255

    markers = markers.astype(numpy.int32)
    #apply watershed
    cv.watershed(im1, markers)

    markers[markers == -1] = 0
    markers = markers.astype(numpy.uint8)
    #return the image as one list, and the labels as another.
    return dt, markers
dt, result = segment(img, img_bin)
cv.imshow('img',img)
cv.imshow('dt',dt)

cv.imshow('img_bin',img_bin)
cv.imshow('res',result)
```

Below one is serving as a guinea pig.

```
import numpy
import cv2 as cv
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv.imread('test001.tif')
gg = img.copy()
img_gray = cv.cvtColor(gg, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

clache = cv.createCLAHE(clipLimit=2.0, tileGridSize=(20,20))
img_gray = clache.apply(img_gray)

cv.imshow('1img',img)
cv.imshow('2gray',img_gray)

#Threshold
_, img_bin = cv.threshold(img_gray, 127, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY+cv.THRESH_OTSU)
cv.imshow('3threshold',img_bin)

#MorpClose
img_bin = cv.morphologyEx(img_bin, cv.MORPH_CLOSE,numpy.ones((5,5), dtype=int))
cv.imshow('4morp_close',img_bin)

#MorpErosion
img_bin = cv.erode(img_bin,numpy.ones((3,3),dtype=int),iterations = 1)
cv.imshow('5erosion',img_bin)

#MorpOpen
img_bin = cv.morphologyEx(img_bin, cv.MORPH_OPEN, numpy.ones((2, 2), dtype=int))
#cv.imshow('6morp_open',img_bin)

#MorpDilate
img_bin = cv.morphologyEx(img_bin, cv.MORPH_DILATE,numpy.ones((1, 1), dtype=int), iterations= 1)
#cv.imshow('7morp_dilate',img_bin)

#MorpBlackHat
img_bin = cv.morphologyEx(img_bin, cv.MORPH_BLACKHAT,numpy.ones((4,4),dtype=int))
#cv.imshow('8morpTophat',img_bin)
```

Comment: Please provide some code, what you've already tried. And, in your sample image, please mark what is noise, what is micro noise, what are structures of interest, etc.

Comment: Done. But, there is nothing about what i've told about. Just some functions.

Answer (score 0):

For those small dots you can try [eroding and dilating](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/db/df6/tutorial_erosion_dilatation.html):

You need to convert the image to grayscale and then process it, I'd create a mask with the eroded and dilated parts to remove those dots and then use that mask on the original image to delete the dots without compromising the resolution of you initial image.

[image]

For the big blury blobs, maybe add some noise to the image and compare with the original?

If most of those blobs are `cv2.HoughCircles` described [here](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghcircles/py_houghcircles.html), it does something like this:

[image]

Of course you can tune those parameters to fit what you want and just ignore those parts of the image. Try that and also the noise, that might help reduce the false positives.
Best of luck!

Comment: Actually, i have already tried those functions, you can see the code below one and it causes to lose some parts of cells. For comparison, i thought about it(but did not applied yet) cells are transparent and i still may lose some parts of it. Maybe in this case i may avoid to lose with erosing.

Comment: Combining the erode and dilate with a circle detection might help to delete only the small blobs up to a certain size. If you have a big enough dataset you could even try cascade filters.

Comment: Allright, i will try that. Sadly, i have only 19 images, and those noises are unique. I can't specify them. Algorithm must specify it.